# javascript .match to check for right coordinate format

Tags: javascript, mgrs

I am using **javascript .match** to check and correct right coordinate format after user writes it in textbox.

**Working example:**

input: lat=57.000000, long=24.000000

code: match(/(\d{2}).(\d{4,9})/gi)

returns: 57.000000,24.000000

**How to write .match algoritme for MGRS coordinate:**

input: 35VLD6787561669, mgrs=35VLD6787561669, etc.

code: ?

returns: 35VLD6787561669 (sequence: 2 numbers, 3 letters, 10 numbers)

Answer (score 3):

According to the [United States Naval Academy](https://www.usna.edu/Users/oceano/pguth/md_help/html/mgrs_utm.htm) the Military Grid Reference System consists of:

- the UTM zone (1-60)
- a latitude band (C-X, excluding I and O; A-B and Y-Z are used for North and South Pole in the polar stereographic projection)
- A two-letter 100K grid square
- 1-5 digits easting
- 1-5 digits northing

The easting and northing define the accuracy and always come in even pairs (2, 4, 6, 8 or 10 digits). The above leads me to the following Regular Expression (Regex) (tested with https://regex101.com/):

#### Solution

```js
/^\d{1,2}[^IO]{3}(\d{10}|\d{8}|\d{6}|\d{4}|\d{2})$/im
```

#### Explanation

- `/.../im` denotes a Regex in Javascript with case-insensitive and multi-line flags (the latter needed for circumflex and dollar sign to work)
- `^...$` circumflex and dollar sign stand for the start and end of the string (otherwise the Regex matches incomplete strings)
- `\d{1,2}`one or two digits
- `[^IO]` all characters except I and O. If you want to exclude North and South Pole, define `[^ABIOYZ]`
- `(\d{2}|\d{4}|\d{6}|\d{8}|\d{10})` 2 digits or 4 or 6 or 8 or 10

Comment: this should be marked as the answer

Comment: for [^IO] wouldn't we have an issue where it would match any letter, whitespace and punctuation as well?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Good catch! This would be better, right? `([C-H]|[J-N]|[P-X])` If you agree, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
([SNsn][\s]*)?((?:[\+-]?[0-9]*[\.,][0-9]+)|(?:[\+-]?[0-9]+))(?:(?:[^ms'′"″,\.\dNEWnew]?)|(?:[^ms'′"″,\.\dNEWnew]+((?:[\+-]?[0-9]*[\.,][0-9]+)|(?:[\+-]?[0-9]+))(?:(?:[^ds°"″,\.\dNEWnew]?)|(?:[^ds°"″,\.\dNEWnew]+((?:[\+-]?[0-9]*[\.,][0-9]+)|(?:[\+-]?[0-9]+))[^dm°'′,\.\dNEWnew]*))))([SNsn]?)[^\dSNsnEWew\+-]+([EWew][\s]*)?((?:[\+-]?[0-9]*[\.,][0-9]+)|(?:[\+-]?[0-9]+))(?:(?:[^ms'′"″,\.\dNEWnew]?)|(?:[^ms'′"″,\.\dNEWnew]+((?:[\+-]?[0-9]*[\.,][0-9]+)|(?:[\+-]?[0-9]+))(?:(?:[^ds°"″,\.\dNEWnew]?)|(?:[^ds°"″,\.\dNEWnew]+((?:[\+-]?[0-9]*[\.,][0-9]+)|(?:[\+-]?[0-9]+))[^dm°'′,\.\dNEWnew]*))))([EWew]?)
```

This worked for me for all geo-locations and also lat/long.

[Here's the gist for this one](https://gist.github.com/moole/3707127/337bd31d813a10abcf55084381803e5bbb0b20dc)

Answer (score -1):

match(/\d{2}[A-Z]{3}\d{10}/gi)

**\d{2}**                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
  **[A-Z]{3}**                 any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (3 times)
  **\d{10}**                   digits (0-9) (10 times)
  **/gi**                      ignore case